# Persist GitHub credentials between Cloud Shell sessions

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

**Is there a way securely persist my GitHub username and PAT in Google Cloud Shell?** (https://shell.cloud.google.com)

Each time I start a new session, I'm asked to re-enter my GitHub username and Personal Access Token (PAT) to allow commands like `git push origin master`. (https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Since the PAT is only visible when you first create it, this means that each day, I need to regenerate a PAT so I can access GitHub from Cloud Shell.

In my local editor, I'm able to store my credentials, reusing the same PAT.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a half-way solution:

`git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout="1000000"`

will store your credentials for a while.

But if there's a "native" way to authenticate the Cloud Shell to GitHub, I'd still love to hear it!

Comment: There's a guide that you can use to save your credentials, you can check this [github link](https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go).